# Search Entire Excell Column for a value that is not always present, if not present create a new value

Tags: excel, vba

i have been trying to find  some help reading a spinet of code i am writing for a larger project. I am looking to identify a string in a column of excel. This string may not always be present in the column, in that case i need to be able to create a new string.

I have created a small macro to test this, currently I have the number 1:20 in column A. The code is searching for "37", and shouldn't be able to find it. 
if the value is found display a msg box to confirm its been found or if it isn't found displays a msg box to say its not been found. If I was searching for "2" the Code works perfectly. I run into issues when the values is not present and "LastPLocation" has no value
Eventually I will need to create a variable and assign it a value eg. a string which says "Not present" or a number "0"

The variables names are taken from the main project, so you can change them.

```
Sub test()

Dim LastPLocation As String

Dim NewLastPLocation as String 

LastPLocation = Range("A:A").Find(what:="37", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If LastPLocation Is Nothing Then

MsgBox ("No Last P")

NewLastPLocation = 0

Else

MsgBox (LastPLocation)

NewLastPLocation = LastPLocation + 1

MsgBox (NewLastPLocation)

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help that you are able to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `lastPLocation` as a `String`, use `Range`:

```
Sub test()
Dim LastPLocation As Range
Dim NewLastPLocation As String

Set LastPLocation = Range("A:A").Find(what:="37", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

If LastPLocation Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No Last P")
    ' Do things here when the value is NOT found
    NewLastPLocation = 0
Else
    ' Do things here when the value IS found
    MsgBox (LastPLocation.Row)
    NewLastPLocation = LastPLocation.Row + 1
End If

MsgBox (NewLastPLocation)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you BruceWayne, worked perfectly :) Have a nice day

Comment: (@CptGoodar - Glad it helped! You can mark it as The Answer, by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows).